# How to find third sigma (or just mean and the standard deviation) of a half-norm distribution?

Tags: r, python, outliers, scipy

I have asked this question on stack overflow but couldn't find the answer there. I have a distribution such as df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 5, 1, 0.9, 0.07, 0.001, 0.00001], columns=['Frequency'])
```

If I first sort this and plot a bar diagram it'd look like:
[image]

I'd like to assume this follows a half-norm distribution, imagine there is another half, and so the mean will be that largest bar in the figure, and then find the mean-3*std. Note, I don't care about the x axis. I tried to simply duplicate all the numbers (the values on the y-axis which are the same as the values in df) and then find mean but the mean and std don't seem to be what I need.

The goal for doing this all is to find the tails in the distribution and remove them. For example, in df I want to remove all values less than n where n is the third sigma and the df follows a half-norm distribution.

Comment: You can read details about a half-normal distribution [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution). However, I doubt that your data are half-normal. If so. I'd expect to see some flattening out towards the right side of your graph. // Suggest you edit your question to explain the source of your data and your goals for analysis. Why would you want to ignore part of your data? Do you question the method by which they were obtained?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The values in df are frequencies of an event and I want to remove the frequencies in the tail of the distribution. In this example, I want to remove all values such as v in df where v is smaller than a threshold such as n and n is the third standard deviation. Hope this is more clear.

Comment: I think it is fair to say that you will not find much enthusiasm on this site for deleting data in this way.

Comment: This is a form of "outlier removal" procedure, so I added the [tag:outliers] to the post.  The data are not well described by a half-normal distribution (and such a description would not be useful for effective outlier detection, anyway).

Comment: BTW, how can a number like "0.00001" be a "frequency of an event"??  If these are relative frequencies, then how can numbers greater than 1 be relative frequencies?

Answer (score 1):

An answer to a question like this can involve several aspects:

- How to fit a half normal distribution (see: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution#Parameter_estimation )
- How to obtain derived quantities from a half normal distribution (see: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution#Properties)
- And not the least, whether trying to analyse this problem with a half normal distribution makes sense. There are several discrepancies like the data being described as a discrete distribution (half-normal is continuous) and also the shape of the distribution is a lot different.

  In addition the motivation "to find the tails in the distribution and remove them" is unclear and points towards an [XY-problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

  (anyways I felt like posting an answer to create a direction for any people that might land on this question in a search; if anybody feels that the first two points do not provide a good answer then ask for more)

Answer (score -1):

If you really assume that your distribution is half of a normal distribution, you can assume that 31.74% of cases are above sigma, 4.55% of cases are above 2-sigma and 0.27% are above 3-sigma.

If you are confident that this assumption is true, you can use the `.quantile()` methodto determine sigma by finding the point above which 31.74% of cases are. This only works, however, if you truly are dealing with a normal distribution.

If you are not dealing with a normal distribution and you just want to know where 0.27% of cases are, you can directly use the `.quantile()` method and ignore the sigma.

Comment: The "sigma" of the parent Normal distribution does not equal the standard deviation of the corresponding half-normal distribution, which arguably is the intended meaning of "sigma" in the question.  You need, therefore, to explain what you mean by "above sigma" etc.  Note, too, that with the example in the question, interest appears to focus on *low* values, not values that are "above" various thresholds.

Comment: If there are enough cases, the standard deviation of a sample becomes a good estimator for sigma. And since 15 is the rarest value and 0 the most frequent, "above" is correct. But yes, it is just an approximation. It is, however, a good one if the only goal of this procedure is to remove the extreme tails (outer 0.27% or >3sigma of the distribution).

Comment: I think I didn't explain myself clearly enough: the issue isn't of an estimate vs. a parameter; the issue is that the meaning of "sigma" for a *half-normal* distribution needs explaining.  The standard deviation of this distribution is *not* anywhere near the "$\sigma$" for the corresponding Normal distribution.  Moreover, using an estimate of the SD is *not* good for this purpose: the multiplier $3$ needs to be considerably increased for small to medium samples.

Comment: Yes, the SD of this distribution does not do any good. But that's not the issue. The question was how to find the long tail of such a distribution that would be the >3sigma tail in a normal distribution of which this is only half. If normality may be assumed, the .6824 quantile would suffice as an estimator of sigma and multiplied by 3. If not, the 0.9976 quantile might be used directly, although it is not nearly as robust. No need to make an outlier analysis more complicated than it is.

Comment: I am unconcerned about complications: my comments are directed only at achieving clarity and reducing the chance your answer will be misunderstood.